# Label every n-th x-axis tick on boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I would like to remove every n-th x-axis tick labels from a `geom_boxplot` (`ggplot`).

For example take this dummy dataframe:

```
Lat <- c(rep(50.70,3), rep(51.82,3), rep(52.78,3), rep(56.51,3))
y <- c(seq(1,2, by=0.5), seq(1,3, by=1), seq(2,6,by=2), seq(1,5,by=2))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Lat, y))
```

I can make a `ggplot` boxplot like so:

```
box_plot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(Lat), y=y))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x="Latitude")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n=6)) +
  theme_classic()
box_plot
```

However I would like to remove the labels from the middle two boxes.

I know I can achieve this by changing the labels to simply be blank (as below).
However, my real dataframe has many more than 4 ticks so this would be time consuming never mind more likely for human error!

```
box_plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=as.factor(Lat), y=y))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x="Latitude")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n=6)) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels=c("50.70", " ", " ", "56.51"))+
  theme_classic()
box_plot2
```

Is there a way to produce the above plot without having to manually set the labels?

For example label every n-th tick on the x axis?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved like. As an example I just plot "every" third tick. Basic idea is to add an index for the factor levels. This index can then be used to specify the breaks or ticks one wants to plot. Try this:

```r
Lat <- c(rep(50.70,3), rep(51.82,3), rep(52.78,3), rep(56.51,3))
y <- c(seq(1,2, by=0.5), seq(1,3, by=1), seq(2,6,by=2), seq(1,5,by=2))
df <- as.data.frame(cbind(Lat, y))

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(Lat1 = as.factor(Lat),
         Lat1_index = as.integer(Lat1))

# Which ticks should be shown on x-axis
breaks <- df %>% 
  # e.g. plot only every third tick
  mutate(ticks_to_plot = Lat1_index %% 3 == 0) %>% 
  filter(ticks_to_plot) %>% 
  pull(Lat1)

box_plot2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x=Lat1, y=y))+
  geom_boxplot()+
  labs(x="Latitude")+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = pretty_breaks(n=6)) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = breaks)+
  theme_classic()
box_plot2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-03-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much! How would I get it to plot the first and then the every 3rd tick?

Comment: Try `mutate(ticks_to_plot = (Lat1_index - 1) %% 3 == 0)`

Comment: Sorry to be a pain @stefan is there a way to force it to label the last tick too?

Comment: (: You are welcome. Try `mutate(ticks_to_plot = ((Lat1_index - 1) %% 3 == 0) | (Lat1_index == n_distinct(Lat1_index)))`. Now the first and every third and the last tick will be labelled.